# Using pip to install pycrypto library on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to download the pycrypto library (I'm using a Mac on High Sierra, and have python 3.6.5). This is the end of the error msg (it's extremely long), if that's not enough I can post more of the beginning as well:

pip install pycrypto

[image: End of error msg]

Comment: what specific command did you try and run?

Comment: @Joe added, sorry

Comment: do you have permission to write to that directory? You could always try '--user' or change permission/ownership of the directory

Comment: @Jonah how would i check if I have permission exactly or change permissions?

Comment: ls -l /Library. relevant discussion here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/weechat-notification-center/issues/1